# Jackson deserialize anonymous complex type results in Unrecognized field ""

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am getting the following exception:

```
Unrecognized field "" (class my.package.RequestParameter), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "value", "name"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 64] (through reference chain: my.package.RequestParameter[""])
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "" (class my.package.RequestParameter), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "value", "name"])
```

when I try to deserialize the following entry:

```
"<requestParameter name=\"myId\">5482973821</requestParameter>"
```

to my target Pojo:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "value"
})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestParameter {
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;
}
```

using:

```
RequestParameter requestParameter = new XmlMapper().readValue(in, RequestParameter.class);
```

Does anyone know what I am missing? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`JacksonXmlText`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlText.html) annotation over your `value` field in your class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestParameter {

    @XmlValue
    @JacksonXmlText //<-- the new annotation
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;
}

RequestParameter requestParameter = mapper.readValue(msg, RequestParameter.class);
//it will print RequestParameter(value=5482973821, name=myId)
System.out.println(requestParameter);
```

Note that if you want to serialize it you will *not* obtain the same starting xml, but it was the same scenario with the code you posted because of the `name` field that will be serialized in a different way from the original xml.